# Usar toLowerCase() em uma array de strings - AngularJS 5, TypeScript

Tags: javascript, array, string, typescript, angular

Estou tentando transformar uma array com strings dentro em lowercase usando toLowerCase, mas parece que não funciona com uma array e sim apenas com uma string... Como resolvo isso?

```
items: Array<{tag: string[], image: string, page}>;

toggledItems() {
  this.items = [
      {
          tag: ['exemplo1','exemplo2'],
          image: '../../assets/imgs/exemplo/ccc.jpg',
          page: Ex1Page,
      },
      {
          tag: ['exemplo4', 'exemplo5', 'exemplo6'],
          image: '../../assets/imgs/exemplo/ci.jpg',
          page: Ex1Page,
      }
  ];
}
```

No codigo abaixo é onde adiciono a array "tag" que esta dentro da array "items". Porém não funciona.

```
if (val && val.trim() != '') {
  this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
    return (item.tag.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta você iterar pelo array de objetos e mapear cada tag.

```
if (val && val.trim() != '') {
  for(item of items) {
    item.tag = item.tag.map(res => res.toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

Afim de poder filtrar as tags de forma que não seja necessário escrever toda a palavra para encontrar o array desejado, é interessante utilizar a função some do javascript. Basicamente ela irá funcionar como um find, porém basta ela encontrar um elemento que atenda ao requisito para retornar true.

Segue o plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/reGXZfiyBBY7GXZT81hG

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Porém quando uso o codigo que me indicou, ele transforma as strings dentro da array "tag" em booleans true, dai a função res.toLowerCase() acusa nao existir...

Comment: Mas o que está transformando as tags em booleanos? Com certeza existe algo a mais no seu código que está fazendo isso, eu testei aqui com esse seu objeto e estava tranquilo.

Comment: Após alguns testes percebi que este trecho ".indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1" está causando a transformação em boolean. Porém não entendo o motivo... (este trecho transforma oq for escrito na searchbar em lower case, portanto é essencial)

Comment: Ele está retornando booleano e é normal, você está perguntando se o Index do valor é maior que -1 (truque para saber se ele existe). Acho que não teria problema em sempre tornar o valor lowercase, mesmo ele não sendo, ou teria?

Comment: Acabei percebendo q a função ".indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1" está adicionando uma boolean no final da array "res" e agindo muito diferente de como devia...

Comment: Não, na verdade ela está agindo exatamente da forma que deveria agir. O porque disso? indexOf > -1? Se sim, true, se não, false. Pq vc precisa desse indexof?

Comment: Ele deveria indicar os itens que aparecerão na lista durante a pesquisa. Exemplo: Eu escrevo "exemplo" na searchbar e ele mostra os dois itens, porém se escrevo "exemplo4" ele mostra apenas o segundo item. Pelo menos era oq deveria acontecer, mas estou com muita dificuldade de consertar isso. Tenho certeza que existe solução simples, porém sou iniciante na programação.

Comment: Segue o plunker com a solução: http://plnkr.co/edit/reGXZfiyBBY7GXZT81hG

Está tudo documentado explicando o porquê das coisas

Comment: Obrigado pelas explicações e pela atenção que esta dando ao meu problema amigo. Testei o código que me enviou e ele funciona assim como eu conseguia fazer o outro funcionar. Porém não da maneira como deve. O conceito é q ao ir digitando as letras, vá aparecendo as imagens cm as tags de letras correspondentes ate somente restar a palavra especifica. Nesse código ai a imagem correspondente somente aparece quando uma palavra da tag esta COMPLETAMENTE escrita e igual a da array... Para o usuário isso é um tanto ruim no quesito pesquisa.

Comment: Acabei de editar o plunker e a resposta, acho que assim será o suficiente.

Comment: FUNCIONOU! Cara, você é sensacional! Sei que é algo simples, mas para mim que estou começando, fazer qualquer coisa funcionar é uma alegria imensa. Tenha certeza de que lembrarei da ajuda e atenção que me deu. Obrigado!

Comment: Qualquer coisa só chamar, fico bem feliz em ajudar